# Is there a reflexive Banach space whose ball is not the convex hull of its extreme points?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a reflexive Banach space. Then the convex hull of the extreme points of the unit ball is weakly dense by the Krein-Milman theorem and Kakutani's theorem. My question is, if there is an example of a reflexive Banach space $X$ whose unit ball does not equal the convex hull of its extreme points? Such an example $X$ must be infinite-dimensional and can't be strictly convex.

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps, but this could be related to Choquet's theorem? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choquet_theory#Choquet's_theorem